# Is it possible to create marker generator within unity apps itself

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

So I'm working on a project to create a marker-based "AR" apps with the ability to show 3D statistics details of a person.
I'm aware that we need to upload the marker's image into the vuforia markers (yes I'm using unity), but I wanted to generate this marker within the apps so users can manually download the image and put it where he wanted.
is it possible to do this (in unity or some suggestion maybe:))?

Comment: Vuforia does have a "user created" option. Or at least, it did the last time I was playing around with it 2-3 years ago. My net is bad enough right now that I can't pull up their site/documentation.